# JavaScript function caching

Tags: javascript, v8

I have JavaScript code which creates tons of functions dynamically at runtime as:

```
f = new Function("a", "b", "something ...");
```

There is high chance that there will be a lot of duplicate functions (meaning same parameters, same body).

Question:
Should I implement some caching algorithm or JS engine (V8) in that case is smart enough to do it itself.

Side-question:
When I debug in IE - it shows (in dev. tools) dynamically created code (I see no duplicate functions - which suggest IE does this chaching).
Do you know a way to show dynamically created code (such as above example) in Chrome dev. tools?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to create tons of functions and not try to reuse a function? Maybe there's a way to reduce this number.

Comment: I doubt there is any sort of caching in either browser. Check `var f = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a+b'), g = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a+b')
console.log(f === g)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That it creates two distinct instances is expected. The question is whether it caches the code for parsing and compilation purposes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case, please?

Comment: Do you have control of the code creating the functions?

Comment: Yes, I do have the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function is a function object. So its subject to GC.

If you are always assigning it to the same reference variable, then previous versions could be trashed by GC.

However, you have to watch out for memory leaks, as having some references to previously defined version of the function will prevent it from being collected.

Comment: So what I should do is to calculate some hash from string (which will be concat of params and body) - cache these string with function. Sounds right?

Comment: BTW - anyone knows how to show such dynamic functions in dev tools of chrome?

Comment: if you can calculate a unique hash for a function, you can create a global object fx = {}, and store all the functions under that object by hash. Next time you need to create a function, just check if fx already contains anything by that key.

Comment: Thanks - will do just that. Any idea about chrome dev. tools?